# Building with boost libraries fails

Tags: c++, boost

I read many questions about this now but I can't seem to link boost libraries. This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 3
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>


namespace fs = ::boost::filesystem;



void getFilesInDir(const fs::path& root, const string& ext, vector<fs::path>& ret)
{
    if(!fs::exists(root) || !fs::is_directory(root)) return;

    fs::directory_iterator it(root);
    fs::directory_iterator endit;

    while(it != endit)
    {
        if(fs::is_regular_file(*it) && it->path().extension() == ext) ret.push_back(it->path().filename());
        ++it;

    }

}
```

Trying to build causes many errors like this:

```
make all 
g++ -lm -g -Wall -std=c++11 -pthread -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system main.cpp -o main.out $(pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs)
/tmp/ccubp4VK.o: In function `getFilesInDir(boost::filesystem::path const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::vector<boost::filesystem::path, std::allocator<boost::filesystem::path> >&)':
/home/nettef/workspace/project//main.cpp:26: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::extension() const'
/home/nettef/workspace/project//main.cpp:26: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::filename() const'
```

I triple checked and `libboost_system.so` as well as `libboost_filesystem` are present in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.

This is the make target:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS =  -lm -g -Wall -std=c++11 -pthread -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system

OPENCV_INCLUDES = $$(pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs)

TEST_LIBS = -lcppunit

CURRENT_DIR = $(shell pwd)

all:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) main.cpp -o main.out $(OPENCV_INCLUDES)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified linker inputs in wrong order. `main.cpp` must precede the libraries it needs:

```
g++ -o main.out -Wall -std=c++11 -g main.cpp -lm -pthread -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system $(pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs)
```

And you probably don't need `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` as it is in the standard linker search path, see the output of `ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR`.

---

I would change your makefile this way:

```
CXX := g++
CXXFLAGS := -pthread -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11
LDFLAGS := -pthread -g
LDLIBS := -lm -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
CPPFLAGS :=

OPENCV_INCLUDES := $(shell pkg-config opencv --cflags)
OPENCV_LDLIBS := $(shell pkg-config opencv --libs)

CURRENT_DIR = $(shell pwd)

all: main.out
.PHONY : all

main.out : LDLIBS += ${OPENCV_LDLIBS} -lcppunit
main.out : main.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^ ${LDLIBS}

main.o : CPPFLAGS += ${OPENCV_INCLUDES}
main.o : main.cpp
    ${CXX} -c -o $@ ${CPPFLAGS} ${CXXFLAGS} $<
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the makefile I'm using to my question. Should `$(CXXFLAGS)` be positioned where `$(OPENCV_INCLUDES) is? Or is `-lboost_system` not actually a CXX flag?

Comment: @speedymcs Added an example makefile for you.

Comment: Thanks! Output is `Makefile:18: *** missing separator.  Stop.` I searched and it seems I need to start the lines starting with `${CXX}` with tabs? When I do that, I again get a lot of errors like `Makefile:22: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:221: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'`

Comment: @speedymcs I missed `-c` option in the recipe for `main.o`, my mistake.

Comment: @speedymcs Yes, use tabs indent commands in recipes. The editor here doesn't preserve tabs.